# Switching between developer environment Windows/Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, windows, apache, ubuntu, mercurial

I have a PC with a dual boot: Win 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 and I have some project in PHP & mySql and sometimes I need to develop under ubuntu (but I usually prefer Windows) but I need to share the files and db's between the two os.

In share I mean if I change some php files or rows in the database that must be visible in both OS. Is it possible?

Extra thing: The most beautiful thing would be if I could get the mercurial in this thing.

Answer (score 1):

- [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) for proper versioning of DB-changes in both OS
- Mercurial in both OS
- External Mercurial hosting (Bitbucket?) for intermediate repository and backup
- Good editor or IDE, in which you can configure EOL-style (in order to have same EOL in Windows and Linux, different by default)

Code in active OS, commit changes to local Mercurial, push to remote.

Before starting work in another OS - pull collected changes from remote